# copy directory from another computer on Linux

Tags: linux, scp

On a computer with IP address like `10.11.12.123`, I have a folder `document`. I want to copy that folder to my local folder `/home/my-pc/doc/` using the shell.

I tried like this:

```
scp -r smb:10.11.12.123/other-pc/document /home/my-pc/doc/
```

but it's not working.

Comment: let me know the other machine os please

Comment: Since they are both linux boxes, there is no need for `smb`. You do need to insure `sshd` is running on `10.11.12.123` in order to allow a secure connection. Then `rsync` is your friend (learn it). `rsync -uav 10.11.12.123:/other-pc/document /home/my-pc/doc/` **Note:** no `/` after `document` (that would copy the contents instead of the directory and contents) If you want to use `scp`, then  `scp -rv 10.11.12.123:/other-pc/document /home/my-pc/doc/`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin suggest you write that as an answer.

Comment: You have not stated the error(s) you are receiving

Answer (score 15):

So you can use below command to copy your files.

```
scp -r <source> <destination>
```

(`-r`: Recursively copy entire directories)

eg:

```
scp -r user@10.11.12.123:/other-pc/document /home/my-pc/doc
```

To identify the location you can use the `pwd` command, eg:

```
kasun@kasunr:~/Downloads$ pwd
/home/kasun/Downloads
```

Comment: user@10.11.12.123/other-pc/document is that name of pc ?

Comment: user@10.11.12.123 in this user is logging username  for the other pc

Answer (score 6):

If you want to copy from B to A if you are logged into B: then

```
scp /source username@a:/destination
```

If you want to copy from B to A if you are logged into A: then

```
scp username@b:/source /destination
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the comment, when you look at your host-to-host copy options on Linux today, `rsync` is by far, the most robust solution around. It is brought to you by the SAMBA team[1] and continues to enjoy active development. Most distributions include the `rsync` package by default. (if not, you should find an easily installable package for your distro or you can download it from [**rsync.samba.org**](https://rsync.samba.org/) ).

The basic use of `rsync` for host-to-host directory copy is:

```
$ rsync -uav srchost:/path/to/dir /path/to/dest
```

`-uav` simply recursively copies `-ua` only new or changed files preserving file & directory times and permissions while providing `-v` verbose output. You will be prompted for the username/password on `10.11.12.123` unless your have setup `ssh-keys` to allow public/private key authentication (see: `ssh-keygen` for key generation)

If you notice, the syntax is basically the same as that for `scp` with a slight difference in the options: (e.g. `scp -rv srchost:/path/to/dir /path/to/dest`). `rsync` will use `ssh` for secure transport by default, so you will want to insure `sshd` is running on your srchost (`10.11.12.123` in your case). If you have name resolution working (or a simple entry in `/etc/hosts` for `10.11.12.123`) you can use the hostname for the remote host instead of the remote IP. Regardless, you can always transfer the files you are interested in with:

```
$ rsync -uav 10.11.12.123:/other-pc/document /home/my-pc/doc/
```

**Note:** do NOT include a trailing `/` after `document` if you want to copy the directory itself. If you do include a trailing `/` after `document` (i.e. `10.11.12.123:/other-pc/document/`) you are telling `rsync` to copy the **contents**, (i.e. the files and directories under) `document` to `10.11.12.123:/other-pc/` without also copying the `document` directory.

The reason `rsync` is far superior to other copy apps is it provides options to truly synchronize filesystems and directory trees both locally and between your local machine and remote host. Meaning, in your case, if you have used `rsync` to transfer files to `/home/my-pc/doc/` and then make changes to the files or delete files on `10.11.12.123`, you can simply call `rsync` again and have the changes/deletions reflected in `/home/my-pc/doc/`. (look at the several flavors of the `--delete` option for details in `rsync --help` or in `man 1 rsync`)

For these, and many more reasons, it is well worth the time to familiarize yourself with `rsync`. It is an invaluable tool in any Linux user's hip pocket. Hopefully this will solve your problem and get you started.

**Footnotes**

[1] the same folks that "Opened Windows to a Wider World" allowing seemless connection between windows/Linux hosts via the native windows server message block (smb) protocol. [**samba.org**](https://www.samba.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If the two directories (`document` and `/home/my-pc/doc/`) you mentioned are on the same `10.11.12.123` machine.

then:

`cp -ai document /home/my-pc/doc/`

else:

`scp -r document/ root@10.11.12.123:/home/my-pc/doc/`

Comment: Meanwhile, the second solution always works either the two directories are on the same host or not.